# Matlab not processing second for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, differentiation

I am trying to validate some accelerator data that I have collected by comparing it against the LVDT displacements that were also recorded. To do this I am trying to differentiate the LVDT data twice to get acceleration. However when I run my code it has the error

```
Undefined function or variable 'DiffDiffLVDT'.
```

Investigating this I have found that Matlab is not processing the second for loop and hence the variable DiffDiffLVDT is never made.

Why is it skipping the second for loop?

```
enter code here
clear all

clc

test2 = csvread('HZ1.csv'); %raw data from excel
time = test2(:,1);
%% Filtering 
f=250;%  sampling frequency
f_cutoff = 2; % cutoff frequency
f_cutoff2 = 5;

fnorm =f_cutoff/(f/2); % normalized cut off freq, you can change it to any value depending on your requirements
fnorm2 =f_cutoff2/(f/2);

[b1,a1] = butter(4,fnorm,'low'); % Low pass Butterworth filter of order 4
[b2,a2] = butter(4,fnorm2,'low'); % Low pass Butterworth filter of order 4

filtaccZ = filtfilt(b2,a2,test2(:,6));
filtLVDTZ = filtfilt(b1,a1,test2(:,7));

%% Remove Offset

Accz = filtaccZ -mean(filtaccZ);
LVDTz = filtLVDTZ - mean(filtLVDTZ);

%% Unit Conversion

LVDTm = LVDTz/1000; % mm to m

%% LVDT Displacement to Acc

% Displacement to Velocity
for d = 2:1:(size(LVDTm)-1)

    x = LVDTm(d+1);

    y = LVDTm(d-1);

    z = x-y; %differnce in y

    a = time (d+1);

    b = time (d-1);

    c = a-b; %differnce in x

    DiffLVDT(d)= (z/c); % Displacement to velocity

end

velocity = DiffLVDT;

% Velocity to Acceleration
for e=1:1:(size(velocity)-1)
    x2 = velocity(e+1); 

    y2 = velocity(e-1);

    z2 = x2-y2; %differnce in y

    a2 = time (e+1);

    b2 = time (e-1);

    c2 = a2-b2; %differnce in x

    DiffDiffLVDT(e)= (z2/c2) %velocity to acc.

end

Acc= DiffDiffLVDT
%% Plotting
close all 
figure
hold on
plot(time(1:5000),Acc(1:5000),'b')
plot(time(1:5000),Accz(1:5000),'r')

grid on;box on
legend('DiffDiffLVDTFilter','Accz')

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
1:1:(size(velocity)-1)
```

does not do what you want it to.

`velocity` is an `1xN` array, `size(velocity)` therefore returns `[1 N]`. The colon operator only cares about the first value in the array and the array you want to loop over ends up being empty since

```
1:1:[1 N]-1 == 1:1:1-1 == 1:1:0 == Empty matrix
```

Due to problems like these you should always use either of the following instead of `size(var)` when constructing loops:

```
size(var, n) % Returns the size of the nth dimension of var
length(var) % Returns the size of the largest dimension of var
numel(var) % Returns the number of elements in var
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and the data matches perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.